# Standard deviation of residuals from a linear regression

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, standard-deviation, residuals

I've ran this linear regression:

```
mtcars_lm <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
```

Lets say I observe a value of `mpg` that is 2 above the predicted value given x `wt`. Am I right in saying this would be 0.67 standard deviations above the predicted value. Here's my workings out:

```
library(broom)
mtcars_lm_df <- augment(mtcars_lm)
2/sd(mtcars_lm_df$.resid)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. You can also extract this result directly from the model object. For example:

```
2/sd(resid(mtcars_lm))

[1] 0.6674783
```